# Why is this html / css not doing what i want

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

This is a script that makes a phone menu. When hovering #menu_button, #menu needs to appear. But nothing happends. How can i fix this?

Feel free to give suggestions to improve my code, im a starter at html and css.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    display: none;
    
}
#header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    
}
#menu_button {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(img/menu_button.png);
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    
}   
#menu_button:hover #menu {
    display: block;
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="menu_button">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `#menu` is not related to `#menu-button` It's not a child (as suggested by your CSS) or a sibling . In fact you would need to hover the header to affect `#menu`.

Comment: Hovering can only affect siblings and children. If you want to affect something outside of that, you'll have to use Javascript.

Comment: Just as a side note: If you refer to a page for mobile devices (phone menu) there often is no chance for a user to hover something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paulie_D said, you can't target element B when hovering on element A unless it is a child or a sibling element. One solution is to put a wrapper around both elements, then use the sibling selector `>` to target #menu when you hover on #menu-button.

See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ceqewivasa/edit?html,css,output) for an example, slightly adapted from yours.

The way you have it written, `#menu-button:hover #menu { ... }` is selecting an element with an ID of `menu` which is **inside** of another element with the id `menu-button`

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript/jQuery isn't mentioned in your tags, I've created a fiddle here which can do this for you in jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/7g80vgv9/

**CSS (slightly modified for this example):**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu {
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    display: none;

}
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
#header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;

}
#menu_button {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 60px 60px;

}
```

**HTML (unchanged):**

```
 <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="menu_button">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
        </div>
    </body>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#menu_button").hover(function() {
   $("#menu").toggleClass("show");
});
```

As you can see, I created a new CSS class called `show` which overrides the `display: none` you have by default on `#menu` with a `display: block !important`.

The jQuery then does the magic by detecting when a user is hovering on the `#menu_button` and executes the code, which in this case is to add/remove (toggle) the `show` class for the `#menu` button.